# Example of norm separable c-star algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I want to know enough examples of norm separable $C^{*}$-algebras which are neither finite dimensional nor commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desire is somewhat vague since you do not write down your motivation.

Did you already browse through K. R. Davidson's book
*$\,C^*$-Algebras by Example* ? (*)
It's worthwhile!

At least kinda start of a list, with
$\mathsf H$ being an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space:

- Compact operators $\:\mathcal K(\mathsf H)$
- Cuntz algebras $\:\mathcal O_n$ with $\,n\in\{2,3,\dots,42,\dots ,\infty\}$
- $\dots$

<sub>* Fields Institute Monograph Volume 6, American Mathematical Society, 1996</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Any C$^*$-algebra which is generated by a finite or a countable set will be separable. Including the examples by Hanno, here is a very incomplete list:

- $K(H)$
- Cuntz and Cuntz-Krieger algebras
- For any countable non-abelian group $\Gamma$, the reduced C$^*$-algebra of the group, $C_r^*(G)$ (namely the norm closure of the span of $\lambda(G)\subset B(\ell^2(G))$, where $\lambda$ is the left regular representation). This includes for instance $C_r^*(\mathbb F_n)$, where $\mathbb F_n$ are the free groups.
- For any countable non-abelian group $\Gamma$, the universal C$^*$-algebra of the group, $C^*(G)$. This differs from the above whenever $G$ is non-amenable.
- Irrational rotation algebras ($A_\theta$ is the universal C$^*$-algebra generated by unitaries $u,v$ such that $uv=e^{2\pi i\theta}vu$)
- AF C$^*$-algebras. That is, direct limits of finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebras. This class is huge, as can be seen by considering their Bratelli diagrams
- Tensor products of the above
- Reduced free products of the above
- $c_0$-sums of the above
- C$^*$-subalgebras of the above

Comment: Another remark: Separability passes to subalgebras. In particular lots of (necessarily exact and quasidiagonal) algebras are subalgebras of separable AF-algebras.

Comment: Indeed. $\ \ \ $